# Is there any difference between the Lebesgue integral of these two rather similar functions?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The first function is

$$f(\omega)={\begin{cases}1, \quad \omega\in \mathbb Q^c \cap[0,1]\\0,\quad \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}}$$

The second function is

$$g(\omega)={\begin{cases}n, \quad \omega\in\mathbb Q^c \cap[0,n]\\0,\quad \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}}$$

The measure space is $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R),\lambda).$

This is not homework; just curiosity.

If the measure space was $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R),\mathbb P),$ given that the set of rational numbers on a given interval have probability $0,$ and the irrationals are its complement, I would say that the integral of both functions is $1,$ and they can be regarded as a pdf. But the measure is Lebesgue, and it's not possible to construct any continuous interval uninterrupted by irrational numbers.

What are the concepts behind understanding the approach to this problem?

Comment: What is $\omega$? And how exactly is $f$ defined in the second case? ANyway, since the rationals have Lebesgue measure zero, you may as well forget about any restrictions placed by rationality of the input, because ultimately if two functions agree a.e relative to $\lambda$, then their integrals with respect to $\lambda$ are also equal.

Comment: The measure of the irrationals in $[0,1]$ is $1$, since the measure of the rationals  is $0$ and the measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$. The measure of the irrationals in $[0,n]$ is $n$< for the same reasons. I don't understand your "But the measure is Lebesgue" comment: single points have Lebesgue measure zero, and Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-additive, so any countable set has measure zero.

Comment: The integral of the first function is $1$; the integral of the second function is $n^2$.

Comment: In each case do you mean $\omega \in$ rather than $\omega =$? Next, since you're talking about different functions, please use different letters for them, don't use $f$ for both functions. Also, in the second function, what should $f(e)$ be equal to? Is it $3$ or $4$ or $5$ or $6$ or... because $e$  lies in every one of the intervals $[0,n]$ provided $n\geq 3$, so your function isn't well-defined.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't understand exactly what's being computed. I have two issues with it: one is the fact that in sigma algebras we talk about countable unions, and the second is that there is no interval without rationals in it.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate. You don't actually say what you want to calculate in the post, you notation is atrocious, and your question is confusing. "There is no interval without rationals in it" is true, but **irrelevant**. Measures, by definition, are required to be $\sigma$ additive. In particular, if $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are measurable and pairwise disjoint, then $\lambda(\cup A_n) = \sum\lambda(A_n)$ (allowing $\infty$ for the sum). The measure of a single point (and hence of any countable set) is $0$; and the measure of an interval is its length.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I got the problem as is from some exercise to students of a prestigious institution. I like the presentations a lot, and I don't want to throw them under the bus. I have no interest in taking any classes, but I was puzzled that I couldn't really understand after listening to the video.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate: Then ask the people who produced the video. Without context, the notation is bad, and your presentation lacking. In any case, you seem to completely misunderstand Lebesgue measure; your focus on "there is no interval without rationals"  shows that you are trying to digest something that is well in advance of the point of your initial confusion, which is what Lebesgue measure is (because that fact, while  true, is, I say again, **utterly irrelevant**). What is being "Computed" is the "net signed area under the graph of the function", just like with any integral.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are right - I have problems understanding Lebesgue measure. I understand that on an interval in the real line is just the difference, but in sets like this, I'm not sure.

Comment: No, the measure of an interval is its *length*. In particular, the measure of a point, which is the interval $[a,a]$, is $0$. It is invariant under translations. And it is $\sigma$-additive. It is meant to be a generalization of "length" for intervals, and it is. Integrals relative to the Lebesgue measure are **just** like Riemann integrals: they measure the net signed area under the graph over the set in question.

Comment: "Sets like this" are easy. *Again*: single points have measure zero. The measure of a finite or countable disjoint union is the sum of the measures, so the measure of a countable set is necessarily $0$. The measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$. So the measure of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ plus the measure of $\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1]$ has to be $1$ (because they are disjoint, and their union is $[0,1]$. But $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$  is countable, so it has measure an infinite sum of $0$s (cont)

Comment: (cont) So $1 = \lambda([0,1]) = \lambda((\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])\cup(\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1]))$ $= \lambda(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]) + \lambda(\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1]) = 0+\lambda(\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1]) = \lambda(\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1])$. So the measure is $1$. Similarly, $\lambda(\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,n])=n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Your last comments are useful at my level of self study. Ty

Comment: @ArturoMagidin [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1535235/878105) nicely summarizes the points where I get stuck on this.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In the end it boils down to a visual: I imagine a ruler, and rational numbers all over the place breaking up the continuity of the irrationals, and making the placement of the ruler at any given spot to measure the length between any irrationals completely impossible. I understand this is non-sense, but I wonder if there is a better mental picture... Perhaps not as topological or geometrical.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate: That's the Riemann view of measuring. The *whole point* of measure theory, which Lebesgue measure is based on, is to abandon that very bad, very misleading view that is only of limited use. What you need to do is abandon the notion that you can have a suitable mental picture of the situation. Like quantum mechanics, you don't need to understand it, you just need to get used to it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin These concepts are mind blowing, and point topology interferes with only apparently coincident definitions to cause true chaos for the casual mathematical tourist. I learned a lot today - painful... A bit... But worth it. [This entry on Quora](https://qr.ae/pGpxM2) is phenomenal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1]=[0,1]/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]/\mathbb{Q}}(\omega)=\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(\omega)-\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}(\omega)$ and the latter indicator here is the Dirichlet jump function. Therefore
$$\int \mathbb{I}_{[0,1]/\mathbb{Q}} d\lambda = \int_{[0,1]}d\lambda-\underbrace{\int \mathbb{I}_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}} d\lambda}_{=0}=1$$
We also have
$$\int n\mathbb{I}_{[0,n]\cap\mathbb{Q}^c} d\lambda=\int n\mathbb{I}_{[0,n]/\mathbb{Q}} d\lambda = n\int_{[0,n]}d\lambda-\underbrace{n\int \mathbb{I}_{[0,n]\cap\mathbb{Q}} d\lambda}_{=0}=n^2$$
This is because the rational numbers are countable:
$$\int \mathbb{I}_{[0,n]\cap\mathbb{Q}}d\lambda = \int \sup_{N \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{I}_{\{q_1,q_2,....,q_N\}\cap[0,n]}d\lambda= \sup_{N \in \mathbb{N}}\int \mathbb{I}_{\{q_1,q_2,....,q_N\}\cap[0,n]}d\lambda=\sup_{N \in \mathbb{N}}\cdot 0=0$$
where I used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: This is great! Thank you! You can read in the comments that I am waddling through this material, knocking my head against properties of sigma algebras and Lebesgue measure, but what you wrote does make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Forensic recap:

The Lebesgue measure on an open interval $(a,b)$ is $\lambda(a,b)=b-a.$ But for a general subset $X\subseteq \mathbb R$ the Lebesgue measure is the infimum additive measure among families of covering countable open intervals $X \subseteq I_1 \cup I_2 \cup\dots:$

$$\lambda(X)=\inf\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(I_n);\; \{I_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N} \text{  covers  }X\right)$$

The prove of the rationals having measure zero is based on building such a family of countably infinite (cardinality of the rationals) set of open intervals covering in this case $q\in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1].$  This family would include sets of the form $\left\{I_n\right\}_{n\in \mathbb N}=\left \{(q_n−\frac \epsilon{2^n},q_n+\frac \epsilon{2^n})\right \} .$ The Lebesgue measure is the infimum of the length of the union of these open intervals:

$$\lambda(\mathbb Q \cap [0,1])=\inf\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda (I_n)\right)$$

And since each interval is $2\frac \epsilon{2^n},$ and the geometric series with a ratio of $1/2$ is $1,$ the total length is $2\epsilon.$ This epsilon can be arbitrarily small, proving the zero measure of the rationals (infimum).

A similar argument relies on covering with the elements of a geometric series of ratio $1/n$ all the rational numbers establishing a mapping from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$ with each element of the infinite sum representing a fragment of a ribbon of total length $\frac{1/n}{1-1/n},$ which can be made arbitrarily short.

The irrational numbers $I =\left \{ [0, 1] \backslash \mathbb Q \right \}$ in the unit interval also get an open cover $\left \{(x − \epsilon, x + \epsilon) : x ∈ I \right\}$ consisting of uncountable disjoint sets; however, their union is not Borel measurable (countable additivity). Therefore, constructing measurable open intervals around singletons leads to non-measurability, and the measurable covering open interval ends up having to the entire $[0,1],$ and can be constructed as $(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon).$

If it were possible to reshuffle the rationals to the beginning of the interval preserving their length (zero), they would leave a length of $1$ for the irrationals (complement subset).